# Select values row-wise based on rank among dates

Tags: r, dplyr, rank, case-when

Let's say I have a data frame with several rows like the following:

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(NA,20,NA),
                 date1 = c("2016-03-01", "2016-02-01", "2016-02-01"),
                 b = c(50,NA, NA),
                 date2 = c("2016-02-01", "2016-03-01", "2016-03-01"),
                 c = c(10,10, 10),
                 date3 = c("2016-01-01","2016-01-01", "2016-01-01"))
```

For each row, I want to get the latest value which is not a `NA` between `a`, `b`, and `c` according to the `dates` (so I respectively look at `date1`, `date2`, or `date3` and pick the most recent one).

Basically, `date1` gives the date corresponding to the value `a`,
`date2` gives the date corresponding to the value `b`,
`date3` gives the date corresponding to the value `c`.

If `date1 > date2` & `date1 > date3`, I will want to take the value `a`
However, if the value `a` is `NA` (which is the case in my example), I will compare `date2` and `date3`. In my example, `date2 > date3` , and since value `b` is not `NA` but `50`, I will take `50` as my final result.

Now I want to do this for all the rows in my dataframe

Since I am using `dplyr`, I tried to use the `case_when` function by using the rank function (in my example, I look a the first ranked date, and then look at the linked value. If it is a NA, I look at the 2nd best ranked, etc...)

However, I can't just put, as I'd like to do, :

```
df <- df %>%
        mutate(result = case_when(is.na(a) & is.na(b) & is.na(c) ~ NA_integer_,
                                  rev(rank(date1, date2, date3))[1] == 3 & !is.na(a) ~ a,
                                  rev(rank(date1, date2, date3))[2] == 3 & !is.na(b) ~ b,
                                  rev(rank(date1, date2, date3))[3] == 3 & !is.na(a) ~ c,
                                  rev(rank(date1, date2, date3))[1] == 2 & !is.na(a) ~ a,
                                  rev(rank(date1, date2, date3))[2] == 2 & !is.na(b) ~ b,
                                  rev(rank(date1, date2, date3))[3] == 2 & !is.na(a) ~ c,
                                  rev(rank(date1, date2, date3))[1] == 1 & !is.na(a) ~ a,
                                  rev(rank(date1, date2, date3))[2] == 1 & !is.na(b) ~ b,
                                  rev(rank(date1, date2, date3))[3] == 1 & !is.na(a) ~ c))
```

Because the `rank` function needs a unique vector as argument (but I can't put `c(date1, date2, date3)` neither because it would give me the whole order of this vector and not the rank for each row)

In my example the result I would like to have would be

```
res

a    date1         b      date2       c    date3       result
NA   2016-03-01    50     2016-02-01  10   2016-01-01  50
20   2016-02-01    NA     2016-03-01  10   2016-01-01  20
NA   2016-02-01    NA     2016-03-01  10   2016-01-01  10
```

Does anyone have an idea or even an entirely different approach to this problem ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest converting to long-format and computing the relevant values. If you want, you can then add the results to your original data.frame. Here's how you could do that using data.table:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)                     # convert to data.table object
df[, row := .I]               # add a row-id
dflong <- melt(df, id = "row", measure = patterns("^date", "^(a|b|c)"),
               na.rm = TRUE) # convert to long format
setorder(dflong, value1)      # reorder by date value
dflong <- unique(dflong, by = "row", fromLast = TRUE) # get the latest dates
df[dflong, result := i.value2, on = "row"]  # add result to original data

df
#    a      date1  b      date2  c      date3 row result
#1: NA 2016-03-01 50 2016-02-01 10 2016-01-01   1     50
#2: 20 2016-02-01 NA 2016-03-01 10 2016-01-01   2     20
#3: NA 2016-02-01 NA 2016-03-01 10 2016-01-01   3     10
```

Comment: Thanks ! I'm impressed by the speed of the algorithm thanks to the use of data.table object

Answer (score 3):

This ought to handle it. First we put the data in tidy form (1 row for each Date, Value, along with a row_num to identify which example the tidy row belongs to). Then we filter out NAs, group_by row_num, order by Date descending, and take the first row.

```
df %>%
  mutate(row_num = row_number()) %>%
  unite(a, a, date1) %>%
  unite(b, b, date2) %>%
  unite(c, c, date3) %>%
  gather(key, value, -row_num) %>%
  select(-key) %>%
  separate(value, into=c("Value", "Date"), sep = "_") %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date)) %>%
  filter(Value != "NA") %>%
  group_by(row_num) %>%
  top_n(1, Date) %>%
  ungroup()
```

[image: Results]

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do it...

```
df$result <- apply(df, 1, function(x){
  dates <- as.Date(x[seq(2, length(x), 2)])
  values <- x[seq(1,length(x),2)]
  return(values[!is.na(values)][which.max(dates[!is.na(values)])])
})

df
   a      date1  b      date2  c      date3 result
1 NA 2016-03-01 50 2016-02-01 10 2016-01-01     50
2 20 2016-02-01 NA 2016-03-01 10 2016-01-01     20
3 NA 2016-02-01 NA 2016-03-01 10 2016-01-01     10
```

Answer (score 1):

Here one more approach:

```
df$row <- 1:nrow(df)

gather(df, key, date_val, date1, date2, date3, -row) %>% 
   select(-key) %>% 
   gather(key, val, a,b,c) %>% 
   filter(!is.na(val)) %>% 
   group_by(row) %>% 
   mutate(max_date = max(date_val)) %>% 
   filter(date_val == max_date) %>% summarise(result = max(val)) %>% 
   left_join(df, by="row") %>% select(-row)

# A tibble: 3 × 7
  result     a      date1     b      date2     c      date3
   <dbl> <dbl>     <fctr> <dbl>     <fctr> <dbl>     <fctr>
1     50    NA 2016-03-01    50 2016-02-01    10 2016-01-01
2     20    20 2016-02-01    NA 2016-03-01    10 2016-01-01
3     10    NA 2016-02-01    NA 2016-03-01    10 2016-01-01
```

Answer (score 1):

Another `base` alternative:

```
df$id <- 1:nrow(df)
d2 <- reshape(df, varying = list(seq(1, by = 2, len = (ncol(df) - 1)/2),
                                 seq(2, by = 2, len = (ncol(df) - 1)/2)),
              direction = "long")

d2 <- with(d2, d2[order(-id, date1, decreasing = TRUE), ])

cbind(df, res = tapply(d2$a[!is.na(d2$a)], d2$id[!is.na(d2$a)], `[`, 1)) 
#    a      date1  b      date2  c      date3 id res
# 1 NA 2016-03-01 50 2016-02-01 10 2016-01-01  1  50
# 2 20 2016-02-01 NA 2016-03-01 10 2016-01-01  2  20
# 3 NA 2016-02-01 NA 2016-03-01 10 2016-01-01  3  10
```

Answer (score 0):

The party was over, but I just came across this post and decided to leave the following. The idea was that I rather wanted to create a data frame and do the job.

```
out <- data.frame(group = 1:nrow(df),
                  date = as.Date(unlist(df[, grep(x = names(df), "[1-9]")]),
                                 "%Y-%m-%d"),
                  result = unlist(df[nchar(names(df)) == 1])) %>%
       filter(complete.cases(.)) %>%
       group_by(group) %>%
       slice(which.max(date)) %>%
       ungroup

cbind(df, result = out$result)

#   a      date1  b      date2  c      date3 result
#1 NA 2016-03-01 50 2016-02-01 10 2016-01-01     50
#2 20 2016-02-01 NA 2016-03-01 10 2016-01-01     20
#3 NA 2016-02-01 NA 2016-03-01 10 2016-01-01     10
```

If I use data.table, I would do the following, which is based on the answer of docendo.

```
setDT(df)[, row := .I]

out <- melt(df, id = "row", measure = patterns("^date", "^(a|b|c)"), 
            value.name = c("date", "result"), na.rm = TRUE) [, 
                 date := as.Date(date, "%Y-%m-%d")][,
                     .SD[which.max(date)], by = row][, c("row", "result")]

df[out, on = "row"]

#    a      date1  b      date2  c      date3 row result
#1: 20 2016-02-01 NA 2016-03-01 10 2016-01-01   2     20
#2: NA 2016-03-01 50 2016-02-01 10 2016-01-01   1     50
#3: NA 2016-02-01 NA 2016-03-01 10 2016-01-01   3     10
```